# TestScoreStatistics While Loop assistance

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

We are supposed to create a loop that repeats for the number of times needed by the student. I am completely lost when it comes to setting up a loop that doesn't run on a predetermined count in the code.

We have to create the loop. I dont really even know where to start since there is nothing in the book that I can see that address that style of condition yet.

Any help is appreciated to get me going in the right direction.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestScoreStatistics
{
   public static void main (String args[])
   {
      int score;
      int total = 0;
      int count = 0;
      int highest;
      int lowest;
      final int QUIT = 999;
      final int MIN = 0;
      final int MAX = 100;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("How many scores would you like to enter >> ");

      enterCount  = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter a score >> ");
      score = input.nextInt();

     //Create a while statement that will loop for the amount entered
      while( count != QUIT )
      {
          }

         System.out.print("Enter another score >> ");
         score = input.nextInt();
      }

      System.out.println(count + " scores were entered");
      System.out.println("Highest was " + highest);
      System.out.println("Lowest was " + lowest);
      System.out.println("Average was " + (total * 1.0 / count));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So. It seems that you want to request entering scores until the user entered as many scores as defined in enterCount:

```
List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
while( count < enterCount ) {
    System.out.print("Enter another score >> ");
    score = input.nextInt();
    scores.add(score);
    count++;
}
```

You probably have to define some kind of List where you put the scores in.